# The second shortest path on a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

The question asks to write an algorithm using Dijkstra's algorithm with time complexity of

$\Theta(|E| \log |V|)$ that find the second shortest path between $s∈V$ and $t∈V$.

The farthest I managed to get is:

1. Run Dijkstra's algorithm and find the path from $s$ to $t$. Mark this path as $P_{(s,t)}$.
2. Remove one edge $e' \in E$ in $P_{(s,t)}$.
3. Run Dijkstra's algorithm on $G' = (V, E - \{e'\})$ and find the path from $s$ to $t$. Mark this
   path as $P'_{(s,t)}$.
4. Define $\text{secondMin} = |P'_{(s,t)}|$.
5. Define $\text{secondPath} = P'_{(s,t)}$.
6. For $i = 1$ to $|P_{(s,t)}| - 1$:

   a. Remove one edge $e \neq e' \in E$.

   b. Run Dijkstra's algorithm on $G'' = (V, E - \{e\})$ and find the path
   from $s$ to $t$. Mark this path as $P''_{(s,t)}$.

   c. if  $|P''_{(s,t)}|<$ secondMin  then secondMin = $|P''_{(s,t)}|$ and
   secondPath = $P''_{(s,t)}.$
7. Return $\text{secondMin}$ and $\text{secondPath}$.

The time complexity of the algorithm is mainly achieved by the loop in line 6:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\Theta(|V|)} \Theta(|E| \log |V|) = \Theta(|V||E| \log |V|)$$

I will tell you where I got stuck:

[image: Here is an example for a graph I tried to work with]

It can be shown that each edge on the shortest path between $s$ to $y$, is the shortest edge between two nodes in the path.
I can't see the point when Dijkstra's algorithm gives the second shortest path (if it does at all).

In order to get the second shortest path, I know that one green edge on the left need to be removed, but I don't know which one, and that's why I used the loop in line 6.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/62383/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18849/755,  https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60355/755

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Daniel from the last link, it appears your question is only feasible for an undirected graph, and your algorithm is the best for a directed graph. do you think so?

Comment: Hello!
I don't think so. 
I know that question asked to use Dijkstra's algorithm.
There for the graph must be directed.
By the way, my algorithm is with a time complexity that is more costly than the time complexity the question asked for :(

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4816788/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/163227/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for bringing my attention.

Comment: @Daniel it's interesting the solution from math SE works for a directed graph and simpler than yen's algorithm, perhaps because you are only asking for second shortest path instead of k shortest path which yen's algorithm solves. indeed it uses dijkstra's algorithm, can you provide the source of your question?